# Cannot get if statement to run in vxml

Tags: coldfusion, vxml

I'm trying to dynamically call an include file for noinput and nomatch, but I can't get the if statement below will not run, any ideas?

This is in a cfmodule tag at the top of every page so I can catch errors, noinputs, nomatch and hangups.

```
<cfif thistag.executionmode is "start">

        <!--- header content goes here --->
        <cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">
        <cfheader name="Cache-Control" value= "no-cache">
        <cfheader name="Expires" value="#Now()#"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <vxml version="2.1" xmlns:voxeo="http://community.voxeo.com/xmlns/vxml">

        <meta name="maintainer" content="#application.maintainer#"/>

        <var name="calledid" expr="session.calledid"/>
        <var name="callerid" expr="session.callerid"/>
        <var name="ivrsessionid" expr="session.sessionid"/>
        <var name="action"/>
        <var name="notes"/>
        <var name="flag"/>
        <var name="recording"/>
        <var name="subdialogid"/>
        <var name="MyEvent"/>
        <var name="currentField"/>

        <property name="universals" value="help"/>

        <cfoutput>
            <property name="sensitivity" value="#session.sensitivity#"/>
            <property name="confidencelevel" value="#session.confidenceLevel#"/>
        </cfoutput>

        <!---This prefetches the audio to optimize performance--->
        <property name="audiofetchhint" value="prefetch"/>

        <!---This logs if the caller hangs up.--->
        <cfoutput>
            <catch event="noinput nomatch error connection.disconnect.hangup">

                <assign name="myPage" expr="'#cgi.PATH_INFO#'" />
                <assign name="MyEvent" expr="_event"/>
                <assign name="action" expr="_event"/>
                <assign name="notes" expr="'Page: #cgi.PATH_INFO# - Field: ' + currentField"/>
                <data name="MyDataName" src="#attributes.historyPath#" namelist="calledid callerid ivrsessionid action notes MyEvent currentField" method="post"/>

            </catch>

            <!---I cannot get the if statement to run--->
            <if cond="'1 == 1'">
                <cfinclude template="../inc/cctypequestionnoinput.inc" />
            <elseif cond="MyEvent == 'nomatch'"/>
                <cfinclude template="../inc/cctypequestionnomatch.inc" />
            <else/>
            </if>
        </cfoutput>



    <cfelse>

         <!--- footer content goes here --->
        </vxml>

    </cfif>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the output? If it generating valid executable code?  If you put that same code into a static file, does it execute?

Comment: What is the value of thistag.executionmode if you dump it out? My guess is it's not what you think it is

Comment: _"I'm trying to dynamically call an include file for noinput and nomatch,"_ - what you're _actually_ doing is including both the files all the time, then using the string `'1 == 1'` as a boolean, which likely evaluates to false, and thus its falling through to the last section (which does nothing).

Comment: Agree with @PeterBoughton. Remove the single quotes around your cond statement and it should run.